# Calling macro inside PROC SQL in SAS

Tags: sas

I need to call a macro code from proc sql in SAS like below.

```
PROC SQL;
 CONNECT TO DB2 (SSID = &DGSYS);  
  CREATE TABLE <DS_NAME> AS  
   SELECT * FROM CONNECTION TO DB2  
    (  
         SELECT * FROM <TAB_NAME> WHERE...       
    );

    %MACRO_CODE(....) --> am calling a macro block of code here

 DISCONNECT FROM DB2;  
QUIT;
```

But this is throwing up an error. Could this not be done?

When I used a macro variable in my query it is allowing me but not a call made to macro code.

The macro would create another macro variable which will be an IN CLAUSE holding values from the previously created table/dataset. And it would be subsequently used in the another CREATE TABLE... in side the same PROC SQL.

Comment: What is your macro doing?  This isn't technically wrong, but the answer depends on your macro.  What is the error?  Is the macro intended to be SQL code?

Comment: @Joe has it right - macros in SAS, as said [elsewhere](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10249455/496803) "_depend on text replacement rather than evaluation of expressions like any proper programming language_". So unless you are dynamically generating code that is valid inside the `proc sql` statement, the macro will likely fail.

Comment: @Joe I have now updated my question

Comment: @athresh Please post your complete code

Comment: First off, what is the error.  "Throwing up an error" is not helpful - *which* error?  Second, we'd need more than what you initially posted in terms of description of the macro.  What's going on inside it?  Is it a %let statement, or a select into, or something else?

Comment: "Macro creates another macro variable" Is there maybe a variable scope problem?  Are they %globals ?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, it sounds like a macro isn't necessary for what you're doing. If you're creating a macro variable containing a list of values from a dataset, you can just use the INTO: clause.

ds_name : Table with numeric and alphanumeric variables.

```
    proc sql noprint;

        /* If VAR_NAME is numeric, this works */
        select distinct var_name
        into: listvals
        separated by " "
        from ds_name;

        /* If VAR_NAME is character, do this instead */
        select distinct cats("'",varname,"'")
        into: listvals
        separated by " "
        from ds_name;

        create table new_ds as
        select *
        from another_ds
        where var_name in (&listvals);

   quit;
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: The macro is called outside ProcSQL, it can not be for a macro variable need.